# Run an animation in Ruby while using TTS gem

Tags: ruby, while-loop, parallel-processing, ascii, text-to-speech

What I'm trying to do is:

1) use the Ruby TTS gem to read some text.

2) while the text is being read, I want to loop through an animation.

The way I'm calling the animation is this:

```
  def animation
    i = 1
    while i < 3
      print "\033[2J"
      File.foreach("lib/narrabot/flair_folder/#{i}.txt") { |f| puts f }
      sleep(0.03)
      i += 1
    end
  end
```

What seems like a quirk (or feature) of the TTS gem is that if you hit a button on your keyboard while it's running... it will replay from where you interrupted...  So, when I tried to run the loop assuming I could just "play" the text, TTS essentially stuttered and didn't run the animation until it ended and then it went back to the beginning.

I just required this gem... https://github.com/grosser/parallel but am not sure how to tackle my goal.

In case you're curious -- my project is here: https://github.com/AdamWeissman/narrabot

What I'm attempting to do is use TTS to read Aesop's Fables... and while a Fable is being read... an ascii animation of a fire will run in the background.  Eventually, I hope to replace the image of the fire with an ascii face (sorta like a sock puppet... the intent is to get the mouth to move in sync -- relatively -- with the speech... but that's a long way off).

Comment: What does "loop through an animation" mean here? For graphical Ruby apps consider [Shoes](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4).

Comment: @tadman thank you for the link to Shoes, I'm grateful to know about it. This project (for school) mandates the user interact with CLI. "loop through an animation" is really: "iterate through a bunch of text files with ascii art, while text to speech plays audio" (I will be more thoughtful with my words next time)...  Lastly, I loved your Takuan Soho quote adaptation -- it was perhaps the thing I needed to read most (without knowing it).  Thank you.